# spring security login always redirect to failure url

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use **Spring Security** in my application, But after hitting the login processing url defined in configure method of **WebSecurityConfig** `Class`, from login page, its always redirecting to the `failurUrl` even if the correct username and password is provided. I have seen a lot of similar problem like this but all of the solutions that were given did not work for me.
There's the code with the security config:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
                permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
         .formLogin().loginPage("/index").defaultSuccessUrl("/userFront",true).failureUrl("/index?error").permitAll()
         .and()
         .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/index?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
         .and()
         .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
         .rememberMe();
    }
    
    
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

And the service responsible for signing in (`UserSecurityService.java`)

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        if (user==null) {
            LOG.warn("Username {} not found",username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username "+username+"not found");
            
        }
        return user;
    }
```

finally the login form (`index.html`)

```
<form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/index}" method="post">
                <h2 class="text-center">Sign In</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                        required="required" roleId="username" name="username"
                        id="username    " autofocus="autofocus">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                        id="password" name="password" required="required"
                        roleId="inputPassword">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign
                        In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <label class="float-left form-check-label"><input
                        type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me">
                        Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </form>
```

What i am missing here please im tired of searching everywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a method in your controller to handle POST to /login?  If not, I suggest you change your GET controller method from /index to /login, change the form to POST to /login, and update the `configure()` method accordingly (change "/index" to "/login").

[Update]

Make sure your login method is only serving GET and let the Spring default handle the POST:

```java
   @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = { "/login" })
   public String index() {
       return "login";
   }
```

Comment: yes i have a methode called index in my controller here it is :

`@RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    } `
and i have changed it to login but it's still redirecting me to a failurUrl  `login?error`

Comment: I think your index() (login()) method is incorrectly intercepting the Spring-provided method for the POST /login handler.  See updated answer for code.

Comment: it's still redirecting me to the `http://localhost:8080/login?error` nothing has changed

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help.  The only other thing I can see is to make sure "/userFront" matches PUBLIC_MATCHERS.